# How to verify a specific method being passed into a mocked method

Tags: .net, moq

I have following method in my *class-under-test*.

```
public Task MethodToTest(string p)
{
   await dependency.SomeMethodAsync(() => dependency.AnotherMethodAsync(p));
}
```

Currently I'm trying to see if it's possible to verify that `dependency.SomeMethodAsync` is actually called with `dependency.AnotherMethodAsync` as parameter.

I manage to mock nicely the first method in my test.

```
mockedDependency.Setup(d => d.SomeMethodAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>())).ReturnsAsync(...);

var response = await myClass.MethodToTest(string.Empty);
```

However, I fail to find a way (if possible) to verify the `AnotherMethod` call.
Following compiles, but throws me a **NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression**.

```
mockedDependency.Verify(s => s.SomeMethodAsync(() => s.AnotherMethodAsync(string.Empty)), Times.Once);
```

Any thoughts on how (and if) this is possible to verify?

Comment: This one is a little tricky as you will have to be responsible for invoking the function delegate which also references the dependency to be mocked. The verify in your example would need to be split to allow for this

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`mockedDependency.Verify(s => s.SomeMethodAsync(() => s.AnotherMethodAsync(string.Empty)), Times.Once);`

With two separate lines:

```
var v = mockedDependency.Object.AnotherMethodAsync(string.Empty);
mockedDependency.Verify(s => s.SomeMethodAsync(v), Times.Once);
```

And, probably, you will have to setup a mock for AnotherMethodAsync.

Comment: Thanks. This would actually work if my AnotherMethod was actually invoked the moment I pass it to SomeMethod. But I'm actually passing it in as a Func, therefore no invocation is done nor registered by the mock object. At least that's what I figured out. So in short, I don't think what I try to do is possible. The only way I can think of is to use an It.Is(Expression) and use reflection to verify the passed in method information. But that starts to look too complex for a unit test :)

Comment: That's for sure. Have you tried verifying first and second line separately, if that helps in your case?